# Docker.service takes 1 minute and 30 seconds causing slow boot

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint, docker

i'm on Linux Mint 19 using Cinnamon 3.8.8 
i have an Nvidia GT740 and 8GB RAM

i'm on : 
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
docker-machine version 0.14.0, build 89b8332
docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471

i noticed that i have a very slow boot

so i ran :

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

and i got the following:

```
1min 27.764s docker.service
     39.269s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     24.180s dev-sdb2.device
     20.645s nmbd.service
     18.437s snapd.service
     13.111s systemd-journal-flush.service
     12.475s udisks2.service
     12.446s NetworkManager.service
     10.969s keyboard-setup.service
     10.734s libvirtd.service
     10.418s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     10.168s networkd-dispatcher.service
     10.065s smbd.service
     9.736s apparmor.service
     ..... etc
```

as you can see docker.service is taking ALOT of time, does anybody know how i could fix this ?

Comment: Any hint in the docker logs?

Comment: @xenoid which logs ?

Comment: Where Docker logs may be distro dependent. I think it is in /var/log/messages for the Redhat church, and /var/log/syslog in the Debian chapel.

Comment: In my system, docker waits to get enough randomness from kernel. So it looks normal but I wish there was a way to not stop login screen when the wait is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I notice this has been on here for years now, but I am facing the same issue today on a dev system with these specs:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker 20.10.17
- docker-compose 1.25.0

Docker.service is taking over 10mins on my system and it is holding the multi-user.target and the graphical.target hostage while it finally starts up leaving my system very unstable in the process. (you can move the cursor on screen, but programs you run wait a long time to actually start)

Since my system is a development machine and is not running critical infrastructure, I just disabled the service:

`sudo systemctl disable docker`

Removing the restart on boot also helps give this some persistence on the long run.
Check your service unit file. `systemctl cat docker.service` If you have `always` in the **Service** stanza, where it says "Restart", you can change it to `on-failure` so it only restarts when it fails (after you purposefully have it running via docker.socket activation) then it won't start at boot time and will save you a lot of time when booting up. This is how I'm using it now:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=on-failure
```

The containerd service and the docker.socket service will still run and in my case, from what I've seen so far, they don't take long to activate (under 30s).

The docker.socket will spawn a new docker.service when needed (if you run a docker or docker-compose command) since this time the docker service is starting **after** the entire system is already up and running, the wait time is severely reduced because anything else that the docker.service relies on is already running and active at this point.

This is what I have observed after disabling the docker service on my system and rebooting a couple of times since then doing my normal day-to-day web-dev work.

Comment: The best solution for dev environments! Thanks, EffectiX

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](https://www.tecmint.com/systemd-analyze-monitor-linux-bootup-performance/) I ran:

```sh
❯ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @42.222s
└─multi-user.target @42.221s
  └─docker.service @38.091s +4.129s
    └─network-online.target @38.082s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @4.450s +33.629s
        └─NetworkManager.service @4.330s +69ms
          └─network-pre.target @4.268s
```

Which shows that docker waiting for the network is the real culprit here.

Then in `sudo systemctl edit docker` I copied the `After` line and removed `network-online.target`, ending up with this:

```
After=docker.socket firewalld.service containerd.service time-set.target
```

This provides a proper solution for those who want docker ready at start :)